# How to suppress a prompt window to continue further

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

As per my application requirement I need to open each form in Access DB to count Activex controls using vb.net. My problem is, one form in the DB is prompting for user input and because of that my application stops until user intervention.

Is there any way to ignore such forms and proceed with scanning DB without user intervention?

Please help me out....

Answer (score 3):

Can't you open your forms in design mode:

```
docmd.openForm "myFormName", acDesign
```

You'll then be able to freely browse the objects in the form and identify your activeX controls.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 

But I am not looking for this. I am able to count Activex Control programmatically but I a want to suppress any user input prompt forms and proceed further.

Comment: By opening your form in design mode you will not be prompted for data input